# Trying to Center my Navigation Bar using CSS

Tags: navigation, center, webmatrix

I am trying to center my navigation bar using my CSS.  I have been able to get it centered by removing the float:left; from the nav ul li.  However, when I do that, the Navigation items are then overlapped by body of my page.  In other words, the Navigation is no longer set apart on top of the page.  Here is my HTML:

```
    <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/About">About Us</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here are the sections from my CSS:

```
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top:  5px;
    }

    nav {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;  
    }

    nav ul {
       /*height: 1px*/
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center; 
        display: inline;
        text-align: center;
        /*float: right;*/
        font-size: 3em;
        list-style: none;
        /*margin: 5px 0 0 0;*/
    }

    nav ul li {
        /*height:  1px;*/
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: .5em;
        float:left;
        margin-left: 30px;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      nav{
          margin-top:0;
          margin-bottom:0;
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
           width:300px;
           }



          nav{

                margin:0 auto;
               width:300px;
             }
```

you could make the width of you nav any size am only using 300px for illustration. the width property is essentail because without it the browser would be unable to center you nav.